# How to deal with this system of equations?

Tags: reference-request, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to investigate this system of equations:

$$
x^Tx-\mathbf{1}^T x=x^TP^tx=c
$$

where $c\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is a given positive integer, $\mathbf{1}=\{1,1,\ldots,1\}$ is a vector with as much ones as elements in $x$ and nothing else, $t\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is any positive integer except if $P^t=I$ and

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 &0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
     1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0    
     \end{pmatrix}$$

is a permutation matrix that shifts the elements of $x$ by one position at a time.

Using alternative notation we can write the same equations as $\sum x_ix_{i+t}=c$ where $i+t$ should be done $\mod n$ (number of components in $x$). and we have different equation for $t=0$: $\sum x_i^2 - \sum x_i=c$.

## Question

I am familiar with basics of linear algebra, matrices etc. but I don't think I am familiar with systems like this one. I need a bit of guidance to get a grasp, anything of the following might be of a great help:

- How do we generally deal with equations $x^TAx=c$? And with $x^TA^tx=c$?
- Is there a special name for this system of equations?
- Is there any theory around such systems, what keywords should I search for?
- More exactly - how can I analyze this system, what can I learn about $x$ from these equations?

## Some results

By summing all of the equations one can find that

$$
  (\mathbf{1}^Tx)^2 - \mathbf{1}^Tx = n\lambda
$$

It's useful to assign the root to $c'$:
$$
  c'= \mathbf{1}^Tx = (1\pm\sqrt{1+4nc})/2
$$

It appears (numerical evidence) that:
$$\sum\limits_{\text{even }i} x_i = (c' \pm \sqrt{c'})/2$$
$$\sum\limits_{\text{odd }i} x_i = (c' \mp \sqrt{c'})/2$$

But I only managed to show that explicitly for $n=2$ and $n=4$. It is done by combining equations to eliminate anything but $x_1$ or $x_1+x_3$ respectively which than turns out to be described by a quadratic equation with the above roots.

Using similar approach I found that for $n=3$:
$$
  \frac{(c'- 2\sqrt{c'})}{3} \leq x_i \leq \frac{(c'+ 2\sqrt{c'})}{3}
$$

Comment: These expressions arose under optimization problems of quadratic functions, being $x^TAx$ the quadratic expression and $c$ the value of the constraint. For convex quadratic problems, the $A$ matrix is positive-definite, which is not the case with $P$, or for most matrices.

Comment: The correct expression is $\sum x_i x_{i+1}=c$

Comment: @hypfco maybe I misunderstood the point of your last comment, but I have not only constraint $\sum x_ix_{i+1}=c$ but also $\sum x_i x_{i+2}=c$ and for any other integer instead of 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let confirm me if these equations are the correct representation of the constraints for the problem?. If you do we can move further into the closed solution.

In algebraic notation:

$$
\mathbf{P}_0: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-x_i=c\\
\mathbf{P}_t,t:1...n-1: \sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_{i+j}=c\\
$$

Thus in matricial notation, we should have:

$$
\mathbf{P}_0: x^Tx-1^Tx=c\\
\mathbf{P}_t,t:1...n-1: x^TP_tx=c\\
$$

with the permutation matrix obtained from the identity or multiplying $t$ times:

$$
P_t=\left[I_{t...n}I_{1...n-1}\right]=P_1^t
$$

and as general case:

$$
\mathbf{P}_t,t:1...n-1: x^TP_tx-\delta_{0t}1^Tx=c
$$

The simplest $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, with $c=1$:

$$
2xy=1\\
x^2+y^2-x-y=1
$$

leads to :
$$
x=1/2 (2 \pm \sqrt 2)\\
y=1/2 (2 \mp \sqrt 2)
$$
[image]

Here it is clear that $\mathbf{P}_0$ is unit nD-sphere 2D-surface centered in $x_i^0=1/2$ and with radius $r=\sqrt{c-n/4}$:

$$
\mathbf{P}_0: (x-x^0)^T(x-x^0)=c-n/4\\
$$

And  $\mathbf{P}_t$ is nD-hyperboloid, 2D-surface, centered in the origin, and having $x_i=x_{i+t},i=1:n$ as the main axis.

Comment: "Let confirm me if these equations are the correct representation of the constraints for the problem?" - yes, both the algeraic and matricial formulations seem correct, I have the same. Only thing that I'd write differently - for drive-by readers it might be more clear to put $x_i^2-x_i$ in parentheses in the first equation.

Comment: I can also confirm the values for the 2-dimensional case. I edited my question to add my own progress.

Comment: Do you realize now this is an intersection of conics?

Comment: Yeah, I understand the 2D case and also the 3D case. But I still have trouble understanding the general case. Like in the 4D case I have $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_1=c$ and $2x_1x_3 + 2x_2x_4=c$. While the first seems like a normal hyperboloid, what is the second? I am not sure how you got the equations for axis but even by using them I can't get any wiser - $x_1=x_3, x_2=x_4$ - that is a plane.

Comment: That is an Hyperbolic Cylinder, that is why you have a plane equation at some directions, and hyperbolas at others.

Answer (score 1):

A good area of mathematics to acquaint yourself with are those results dealing with the [numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range).  The numerical range of the matrix $P^t$ is

$$\left\{\mathbf{y}^*P^t\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{C}^n,\ ||y||_2=1\right\},$$

which is a normalized version of the quadratic form that you're interested in.  Note that $P^t$ in your case is a normal matrix, which implies that the numerical range of $P^t$ is the convex hull of the eigenvalues of $P^t$ (and therefore $P$).  If a scalar $d\ne 0$ lies in the numerical range of $P^t$ for a particular unit vector $y,$ then you can construct a desired solution $x=\sqrt{\frac{c}{d}}y.$

Answer (score 1):

I asked for references on the method used below at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr 
My preference is to write the steps as separate matrices and multiply them together; thus you find, below, r = r1 * r2 * r3 * r4 for example

There is a way to avoid eigenvalues and still get a diagonal quadratic form. It seems the eigenvalues are nice in even dimension but less nice in odd dimension. Double your thing reads
$$ 2 x^T x - x^T(P + P^T)x - 2 1^T x = 2c.  $$
The first point is that a quadratic form depends only on the symmetric part of the coefficient matrix.

$$  H = 2I - P^T - P. $$

Next, with a symmetric integer matrix, we can arrange a rational matrix of determinant $1,$ I called it $R,$ such that
$$ R^T H R = D $$ is rational diagonal. Since $R$ is upper triangular of determinant $1,$ it is not such a big deal to find $R^{-1},$ which you will likely want.

If I get the patience I will typeset later, meanwhile there is a pattern, here is $n=5,$ below that $n=6.$

```
? h
%32 = 
[2 -1 0 0 -1]

[-1 2 -1 0 0]

[0 -1 2 -1 0]

[0 0 -1 2 -1]

[-1 0 0 -1 2]

? r = r1 * r2 * r3 * r4
%28 = 
[1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1]

[0 1 2/3 1/2 1]

[0 0 1 3/4 1]

[0 0 0 1 1]

[0 0 0 0 1]

? rt = mattranspose(r)
%29 = 
[1 0 0 0 0]

[1/2 1 0 0 0]

[1/3 2/3 1 0 0]

[1/4 1/2 3/4 1 0]

[1 1 1 1 1]

? d = rt * h * r
%31 = 
[2 0 0 0 0]

[0 3/2 0 0 0]

[0 0 4/3 0 0]

[0 0 0 5/4 0]

[0 0 0 0 0]
```

=======================================================

```
? r = r1 * r2 * r3 * r4 * r5
%25 = 
[1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 1]

[0 1 2/3 1/2 2/5 1]

[0 0 1 3/4 3/5 1]

[0 0 0 1 4/5 1]

[0 0 0 0 1 1]

[0 0 0 0 0 1]

? rt = mattranspose(r)
%26 = 
[1 0 0 0 0 0]

[1/2 1 0 0 0 0]

[1/3 2/3 1 0 0 0]

[1/4 1/2 3/4 1 0 0]

[1/5 2/5 3/5 4/5 1 0]

[1 1 1 1 1 1]

? h
%27 = 
[2 -1 0 0 0 -1]

[-1 2 -1 0 0 0]

[0 -1 2 -1 0 0]

[0 0 -1 2 -1 0]

[0 0 0 -1 2 -1]

[-1 0 0 0 -1 2]

? d = rt * h * r
%28 = 
[2 0 0 0 0 0]

[0 3/2 0 0 0 0]

[0 0 4/3 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 5/4 0 0]

[0 0 0 0 6/5 0]

[0 0 0 0 0 0]

?
```

=============================

Comment: How exactly do I use the $R$ to get the $x$? Also the first equation should probably read $2 x^T x - x^T(P + P^T)x - 2 1^T x = 0$.